# How to prevent firefox from scrolling to the bottom of the page when a large popup is opened

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

I use a simple onClick event to display a popup in my application. When the popup size is large, the screen is automatically scrolled down to the bottom of the page after the popup appears. I am only facing this problem in Firefox browser. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From the design and usability perspective you should not allow any pop-up on your web page to exceed the given view-port limit, for example half of the window height.

Try to make the pop-up div with fixed height and with `overflow-y: scroll`, so if there is more content - the user will be able to scroll down and read it.

*In general, you should use Pop-ups carefully.*

Unfortunately, the bad pop-ups give all pop-ups a bad name. Some users even turn off JavaScript in their browsers or download special software utilities to kill all pop-up windows.

Many do this in desperation because pop-up windows are stalking them wherever they go on the Web - and most people don't realize that they are partly to blame. Often, they've downloaded some free utility or music-sharing program that contains a scum-ware program that tracks your movements online, steals your personal information, and makes your online life miserable by continually harassing you with pop-up advertising!

See [this](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window), [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pop-up_ad) article and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114024/modal-popups-usability) SO question.